# Automount Samba directory as /home/$user

Tags: samba, home, automounting

I'm working with a group, trying to set up persistent data on several thin clients for our Linux lab. For security and maintenance reasons, we want to be able to flash a clean snapshot of Arch Linux onto the thin clients every night so any user changes (and mess ups) will be changed back to their original state.

We'd like to set it up so that when a user logs in, the Samba share is mounted as `/home/$user`. That way, any changes in the users home directory and below is saved onto a network server instead of being wiped.

How can we set things up so that a user's home directory is mounted from Samba when they log in unmounted when they log out?

Comment: OK, so what part of this is the issue? Also, why samba? Are there any Windows machines involved? If not, use NFS instead.

Comment: I don't see a question mark anywhere... Are you asking for a smb.conf?